# Reading first line of a text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, version, text-files

Let's say I have a text file on my web server under `/today/changelog-en.txt` which stores information about updates to my website. Each section starts with a version number, then a list of the changes.

Because of this, the first line of the file always contains the latest version number, which I'd like to read out using plain JavaScript *(no jQuery)*. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: is the file available externally? ie: can it be reached via an XHR/AJAX request?

Comment: Don't know anything about AJAX.

Comment: Would you hypothetically be able to provide a url that would result in the txt file in question? If so I can show you what code to write to achieve the results you're looking for.

Comment: cool, then we can just make a XHR request, will post an answer now.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Is your website hosted on hunpony.hu?

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr I always get jQery answers which I don't feel like learning now, that's why it's there.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I feel you :} I'm more of a CoffeeScript person

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be simple enough using XHR. Something like this would work fine for you:

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.open("GET", "/today/changelog-en.txt", true);
XHR.send();
XHR.onload = function (){
    console.log( XHR.responseText.slice(0, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")) );
};
```

Comment: And how do I make this working with an HTML file?
Edit: Now makes sense :D

Comment: @DJDavid98 Simply put it in the `script` tags. Where you see `console.log`, put some function that uses the version number.

Comment: Yeah, I know, only that 1 line was missong from the top. Works great!

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yeah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

So seeing as the txt file is externally available ie: corresponds to a URL, we can do an XHR/AJAX request to get the data. Note without jQuery, so we'll be writing slightly more verbose vanilla JavaScript.

```
var xmlHttp;

function GetData( url, callback ) {

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}

GetData( "/today/changelog-en.txt" , function() {

    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 {

        var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
        var allLines = result.split("\n");

        // do what you want with the result 
        // ie: split lines and show the first line

        var lineOne = allLines[0];

    } else {
        // handle the error
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but Amaan's version is much more compact. That does not mean yours is bad, it's just that I like to do it the simpiest way possible.

Comment: well its up to you, though, mine has the ability to re-use the code, and handle errors responsibly.