# Get the contents of a text file into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a desktop notification. I'm using this code to show it, and its working fine:

```
// If the user is okay, let's create a notification
if (permission === "granted") {
  var options = {
    body: "This is the body of the notification",
    icon: "icon.jpg",
    dir : "ltr"
  };
  var notification = new Notification("Hi there",options);
}
```

But how can I fetch data from a text file into `options.body`?

Comment: Where is the text file coming from?

Comment: If you want to load a text file you can use Ajax. But you need to set up a web server before using Ajax.

Comment: text file is coming from server.. notificion.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading first line of a text file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227729/reading-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-javascript) (just use `XHR.responseText` instead of slicing)

Comment: can you please put into my code.. sorry im just new into javascript..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227851/1344955), the finished result should look like this:

```
// If the user is okay, let's create a notification
if (permission === "granted") {
  var options = {
    icon: "icon.jpg",
    dir : "ltr"
  };
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XHR.open("GET", "notificion.txt", true);
  XHR.send();
  XHR.onload = function (){
    options.body = XHR.responseText;
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there",options);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using JQuery `$.get()`

```
if (permission === "granted") {
  $.get("notificion.text", function(data) {
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there", {
      icon: "icon.jpg",
      dir: "ltr",
      body: data
    });
  });
}
```